# .NET regular expression to extract 1-4 digit value from mixed character value

Tags: .net, regex, string, expression

What I am trying to accomplish a .NET regular expression for the following strings:

> Example 1. **abc1234abc** - *1234*
>   Example 2. **abc12345abc** - *no results*
>   Example 3. **abc1234abc12345** - *1234*

I am trying to extract a 1-4 numeric (`1`, `12`, `123`, or `1234`) from any mixed character value but no more than 4 digits  (IE. NOT `12345`).

The `[0-9]{1,4}` pattern yields:

> Example 1. **abc1234abc** - *1234 (good)*
>   Example 2. **abc12345abc** - *1234, (should return no results)*
>   Example 3. **abc1234abc12345** - *1234, 1234, 5 (should return ONLY 1234)*

What am I missing? Thank you for the help, I am very much new to regular expressions and I could not find what I am looking for anywhere. I hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the lookarounds that will check the number is not enclosed with more digits:

```
(?<!\d)\d{1,4}(?!\d)
```

Or (if you need to only match regular digits excluding all Uncide ones in Hindi, etc.):

```
(?<![0-9])[0-9]{1,4}(?![0-9])
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!%5Cd)%5Cd%7B1%2C4%7D(%3F!%5Cd)&i=abc1234abc%0D%0Aabc12345abc%0D%0Aabc1234abc12345)

The `(?<!\d)` is a negative lookbehind that checks if the next subpattern is not preceded with some other subpattern (looks before the current position, "looks behind"), and `(?!\d)` is a negative lookahead that makes sure that there is no digit after the current position ("looks ahead"). Lookarounds do not consume characters, they just check and then return true or false (thus allowing or failing a match), so, you only get your expected match as a result.

More [details on regex lookarounds at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Will do, and I'll try to format my question correctly next time. Thanks again for your help, this was driving me nuts. :)